# Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I'm running on macOS 10.12, and I'm trying to install Django using:

```
pip install Django==1.10.5
```

I get this error:

```
Your PYTHONPATH points to a site-packages dir for Python 3.x but you are running Python 2.x!
 PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:"
 You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

I have Python3 and Python2.7 installed with macOS on my system, but I really only want to use Python3 for pretty much everything. Pretty new to using / configuring Python, has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Use `pip3` instead of `pip` if you want to use python3. Also, consider using a `virtualenv`.

Comment: For an introduction to the PYTHONPATH and virtualenv, http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll definitely want to use a `virtualenv` to separate your Django project from the system Python version. `virtualenv` creates a virtual environment - a dedicated version of Python just for your Django project - so you don't install any libraries with the system Python version, which is used for many other things. `virtualenvwrapper` makes working with `virtualenv` easy. `pip install virtualenvwrapper` is your friend. Here's how to install:

```
# Install virtualenvwrapper with the system Python version
pip install virtualenvwrapper
# Then, add these lines to your .bashrc, with the appropriate path to Python 3
# You can find the path to Python 3 with "which python3"
# virtualenvwrapper.sh is typically in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin 
export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.5
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

After that initial install, here's how to work with virtualenvwrapper:

```
# Make a virtualenv
mkvirtualenv my_project

# You're now in the environment for your project
pip install Django

# When you need to activate the virtualenv to work on your project
workon my_project

# Show the virtualenvs you've created - I use one for each Django or Python project I create
lsvirtualenv
```

Much more here: https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have `site-packages` in your `PYTHONPATH` at all; it's already going to be in `sys.path` for the appropriate version of Python, but having it in `PYTHONPATH` mean the other version of Python will try to use the incompatible modules found there. Figure out where you are setting `PYTHONPATH` to that (it shouldn't happen in any default setup, so you probably did the wrong thing in `~/.bashrc` or the like manually), and stop doing it. If you can't figure it out, `unset PYTHONPATH` will remove it.

Since you want to use Python 3, use `pip3` for package management, not `pip`.

Comment: Are you saying that only python2 used a site-packages folder?

Comment: @GabrielFair: No, all versions use it, but it's located under `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, where X and Y are specific Python versions.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was just missing that folder then.